# Game engine components Issue

Tags: c#, game-engine, gdi+

I'm currently developing a game engine using GDI+ in C#. At the moment I'm implementing components. Components can be attached to game objects. Game objects are rendered to a Screen, which is displayed on the window/form.

Before I continue, take a look at these few lines in the GameObject class:

```
    private List<Component> components = new List<Component>();

    public GameObject()
    {
        AddComponent(new Transform());
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        components.ForEach(c => c.OnUpdate(gameTime));
    }

    public void Render(GraphicsEngine graphicsEngine)
    {
        components.ForEach(c => c.OnRender(graphicsEngine));
    }

    public void AddComponent(Component component)
    {
        component.gameObject = this;
        components.Add(component);
    }

    public T GetComponentOfType<T>() where T : Component
    {
        return (T)GetComponentOfType(typeof(T));
    }

    private Component GetComponentOfType(Type type)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < components.Count; i++)
            if (components[i].GetType() == type)
                return components[i];

        return null;
    }

    public Transform Transform
    {
        get { return GetComponentOfType<Transform>(); }
    }
```

Now hopefully things might be a little clearer to you when I show you the next piece of code.

Basically, I have a method which loads a bunch of game objects from an XML file. But for some reason, depending on the way I add the sprite component to the game object, sometimes it doesn't work properly and only some of the game objects sprites render to the screen

Here is part of the code from the method which loads game objects:

```
 // Creates the object and sets the position
 GameObject obj = new GameObject();
 obj.Transform.Position = new Maths.Vector2(x * map.TileWidth, y * map.TileHeight);

 // This works and renders all sprites to the screen
// obj.AddComponent(new SpriteComponent(sprs[sprID].Bitmap));

// This works and renders all sprites to the screen
// obj.AddComponent(new SpriteComponent());
// obj.GetComponentOfType<SpriteComponent>().Bitmap = sprs[sprID].Bitmap;

 // This doesn't work and only renders some sprites to the screen
 obj.AddComponent(sprs[sprID]);

 // Adds the game object to the screen
 screen.AddGameObject(obj);
```

Just to clarify, sprs is a list of sprite components

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by " sometimes it doesn't work properly". Ignoring the function of the application, are you saying that the line "obj.AddComponent()" does not lead to a component being added to the components list ? That seems unlikely. I think its much more likely that you are not handling GDI+ Bitmap objects properly as these need careful lifetime management. We dont have a complete picture of the code here - we can't see how sprs[] is being created so if I entered your code sample into VS.net it would not compile. We would need a verifiable example to assist.

Comment: If you read the comments in my code I said "This doesn't work and only renders some sprites to the screen". The sprs[] is a list of SpriteComponents and is being created using the new keyword (sprs = new List<SpriteComponents>();). The sprite components are all being added to the screen but for some reason not all of them are being rendered when I pass a sprite component from the sprs list to the AddComponent method.

Comment: - are you saying that the line "obj.AddComponent()" does not lead to a component being added to the components list ? or just that they dont render correctly ?

Comment: @PhillipH The obj.AddComponent() method does add a component to the list, but when I write this line "obj.AddComponent(sprs[sprID]);" instead of the other two options, not all o the sprites render to the screen. So to recap, all components get added to the list, but not all of them render to the screen when I use the line "obj.AddComponent(sprs[sprID]);"

Answer (score 0):

Ok - the most likely explanation is that AddComponent puts a reference to the game object into the Component before adding it to the list, but I'm guessing your sprs[] array construction does not - pretty hard to tell without all the code.

Comment: Well, it turns out that not every Component gets assigned a game object... I'm not sure why that is, but I found out by iterating through the components list, and seeing if the components reference to the game object was null and correcting it.

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct myself, the game object reference isn't null, it just doesn't equal this... Which is odd